# Android Get XML from URL as string

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I am very new to Android Development and Java,
I have C# experience
anyway
I am trying to get XML from a URL
I tried every possible thing but non is working.
Always get crash or no result.

I just want a simple XML result, I found some JSON and PHP code, that i do not want to connect to MySQL.

is there any simple function to retrieve the XML as string from a URL

this is one of my traials

`
        lbl1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl1);

```
try {
        InputStream is = new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml").openConnection().getInputStream();
        String strxml = is.toString();
        lbl1.setText(strxml);
    }
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is old tutorial, you should communicate with server only is background thread or use [AsyncTask of android.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: "I tried every possible thing" I don't believe that. For example you did not try the right thing. Hint: review what `String strxml = is.toString();` is doing.

Comment: Thanks Henry, I know I did not try the right thing, otherwise I would not be posting this. when people post here that means they need technical help, not a language advisor.

Comment: @VenomVendor how would an AsyncTask help when 'toString()' is clearly not the way to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you do it in C#? 
URL.toString() and (in c#) Request.Url.ToString() are alike. Both behave the same way: creating a string of the URL.

(Like in C#) you would need a HTTP client: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html